# Removing lines within filled.contour legend

Tags: r

I might be missing something simple here... I can't find anyway to remove the lines that cross the legend differentiating different colours; following on the from the volcano topography example in `?filled.contour`, I've got this:

```
x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)

filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color = terrain.colors,
   plot.title = title(main = "The Topography of Maunga Whau",
    xlab = "Meters North", ylab = "Meters West"),
    plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(100, 800, by = 100))
              axis(2, seq(100, 600, by = 100)) },
    key.title = title(main="Height\n(meters)"),
    key.axes = axis(2,
          labels=FALSE,
          at=FALSE,
          lty=NULL,
          tick=FALSE,
          col="white",
          col.ticks=NULL)
)
mtext(paste("filled.contour(.) from", R.version.string),side = 1, line = 4, adj = 1, cex = .66)
```

I've managed to remove all the labels and tick-marks from the axis, but the lines still exist (incidentally, the effect I'm trying to achieve is (I believe) the default in Matlab!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you examine the code for `filled.contour` you'll see this line:

```
rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1L], col = col)
```

that draws the color key rectangle. It's vectorized, so it's drawing each of the individual color boxes. The function `rect` accepts an argument `border`, which if you set to `NA` will omit the internal borders of the rectangles. So create your own version of the function and change this line to :

```
rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1L], col = col, border = NA)
```

or make it an argument, rather than hard coding. When I do this, I get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't expecting it to be that complicated though!

Comment: @ChrisW It doesn't seem that complicated to me, though maybe I'm just used to it. The authors of functions like `filled.contour` can't anticipate _every_ possible tweak a user will want to make.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to change the filled.contour hardcode. Apparently the argument `border` in the function `rect` relies on `par("fg")`. Just set `par(fg = NA)` to remove those black lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you set ``par(fg = NA)`` you will wipe out the delimiting borders on the legend and axes.

Comment: Thus it is the case but you can always manually set 'borders = "black" ' and ' col="black" ' to get them back.