# Placing rows at user-defined distances in filled.contour in R

Tags: r, plot, contour

I am trying to create filled.contour using the following matrix.

```
row1 <- rep(10,100)
row2 <- sample(c(10:30),100,replace=TRUE)
row3 <- rep(30,100)
z1 <- cbind(row1,row2,row3)
col1 <- colorRampPalette(c('red','yellow','deepskyblue'))(20)
filled.contour(z=z1,col=col1,cex.lab=2,cex.main=1.1,nlevels=20,main=('Heat map'))
```

I get the following plot:

[image]
(**You won't see the border in the legend because I have modified** `filled.contour` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068366/removing-lines-within-filled-contour-legend))

You can see that `row2` is placed exactly in the middle(at position 0.5 with respect to the axis). my question is as follows:

*Is it possible to put the rows not symmetrically but on user defined locations? For example, I am requiring to put the rows at positions* `c(0,.33,1)` *and not the default* `c(0,.5,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I waited for some response here, I kept on trying and actually it was a very silly problem.
You just need to change the default `y` argument in `filled.contour`

Here is the (not significantly) modified function which gives the following image:

```
filled.contour(z=z1,y=c(0,.33,1),col=col1,cex.lab=2,cex.main=1.1,nlevels=20,main=('Heat map with custom y placement'))
```

[image]